# Issue dismounting LVM on LUKS system when initial live-USB isn't present

Tags: live-usb, shutdown, lvm, luks, unmount

I am having a rather peculiar problem with the Ubuntu half of my system. The TL;DR is that I have Ubuntu 14.04 using an LVM on LUKS setup. /boot lives on an unencrypted partition (/sda3) while swap and root live on an LVM inside a LUKS partition (/sda4). I did the setup from a live-USB and the system mostly works. However, the system's behavior depends on if the original live-USB is present or not.

If the USB is present, the system boots in roughly ~3 seconds and will cleanly shutdown. If the USB is not present, the encrypted system will mount but the login process takes ~60 seconds. On shutdown, the system claims root is busy and will not shutdown cleanly.

I am unsure what exactly the problem is, or how I would go about fixing it. I suspect the problem is a result of me doing something wrong when I chroot'ed from the live-USB to the new install during the setup. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm including as much information as possible and apologize if the rest of this post is unnecessarily long.

**Output During Shutdown:**

If the live-USB is present, the shutdown proceeds normally:

```
wait-for-state stop/waiting
 * Stopping rsync daemon rsync [OK]
 * speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
 * Asking all remaining processes to terminate... [OK]
 * Killing all remaining processes... [OK]
ModemManager[971]: <info> Caught signal, shutting down...

ModemManager[971]: <info> ModemManager is shut down

nm-dispatcher.action: Caught signal 15, shutting down...
 * Deactivating swap... [OK]
 * Unmounting local filesystems... [OK]
 * sda4_crypt (busy)...
 * Stopping early crypto disks... [fail]
 * Stopping early crypto disks... [OK]
 * Will now halt
[ 155.0007241 reboot: Power down
```

The system cleanly shuts down and we have no problems.

If the live-USB is not present, shutdown proceeds as:

```
wait-for-state stop/waiting
 * Stopping rsync daemon rsync [OK]
 * speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
 * Asking all remaining processes to terminate... [OK]
 * Killing all remaining processes... [fail]
ModemManager[971]: <info> Caught signal, shutting down...

ModemManager[971]: <info> ModemManager is shut down

nm-dispatcher.action: Caught signal 15, shutting down...
 * Deactivating swap... [OK]
 * Unmounting local filesystems... [OK]
 * sda4_crypt (busy)...
 * Stopping early crypto disks... [fail]
 * Stopping early crypto disks... [OK]
mount: / is busy
 * Will now halt
[240.184072] INFO: task kworker/6:1:124 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[240.184132]       Not tainted 3.19.0-47-generic #53~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[240.184176] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[240.184418] INFO: task alsa-sink-USB A:2037 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[240.184469]       Not tainted 3.19.0-47-generic #53~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[240.184512] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[240.184710] INFO: task pulseaudio:2563 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[240.184758]       Not tainted 3.19.0-47-generic #53~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[240.184802] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

At this point, the system justs continues to post the above errors at regular intervals and never properly shuts down. The only way to fix this is to manually power off the machine.

**Setup:**

I'm dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 on a desktop. Prior to installing Ubuntu, I installed Windows 10 and encrypted it using VeraCrypt. These two use /sda1 and /sda2. I then tried to install Ubuntu from a live-USB loosely following these two guides:

[1] https://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu

[2] http://techblog.mastbroek.com/all-articles/dualboot-encrypted-windows-and-ubuntu/5/

I mostly followed [1] and basically only referenced [2] for setting up an LVM. /boot is on the unencrypted partition /sda3 while swap and root are on an LVM inside a LUKS partition, /sda4. Everything is done using UUIDs. When all is said and done, my system looks like:

```
$ sudo lsblk -o name,uuid,mountpoint
NAME                          UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                  
├─sda1                        16808C90808C784F                       
├─sda2                                                               
├─sda3                        41589165-270f-4be5-bbfd-7fe66112f485   /boot
└─sda4                        dd217bb3-30f3-496a-8dc9-12abc62e0b0f   
  └─sda4_crypt (dm-0)         BJA0uf-k4EW-SpaJ-GfTN-5orX-K5AM-IGuKcD 
    ├─MyVolume-swapvol (dm-1) 71149c9e-22b7-4349-8045-a632f2ff63c6   [SWAP]
    └─MyVolume-rootvol (dm-2) 1c5cf473-72a5-4066-b65e-2fdbe78fa231   /
sdb                                                                  
├─sdb1                        8EBC75B8BC759C01                       
└─sdb2                        D20877650877478D                       
sdc                                                                  
└─sdc1                        68463BC6463B9432                       
sdd                                                                  
└─sdd1                        B88407A8840767E8                       
sr0
```

Contents of fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=1c5cf473-72a5-4066-b65e-2fdbe78fa231 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=41589165-270f-4be5-bbfd-7fe66112f485 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
UUID=71149c9e-22b7-4349-8045-a632f2ff63c6 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Contents of crypttab:

```
sda4_crypt UUID=dd217bb3-30f3-496a-8dc9-12abc62e0b0f none luks,discard,lvm=MyVolume
```

As far as I can tell, everything above looks correct. I suspect the issue isn't with mounting / unmounting the encrypted system, but rather with some strange dependency with files on the live-USB. This seems to imply something went wrong with Steps 6 of guide [1] when I chroot'ed from the live-USB to the encrypted file system. The relevant commands (directly from [1]), starting from within the live-USB are:

```
cd /mnt
mkdir root
mount /dev/mapper/root root
mount /dev/mapper/sda1 root/boot
chroot root
mount -t proc proc /proc
mount -t sysfs sys /sys
```

When actually doing this, I changed /sda1 and /dev/mapper/... as needed for my system.

If this is in fact where something went wrong, I have no idea how to even diagnose the problem let alone fix it.